# Django admin - foreign key "field object" list

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have the following code:

```
class Actor(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField('First Name', max_length=135)
    last_name = models.CharField('Last Name', max_length=135)

    class Meta:
        db_table = u'actor'

    def actorname(self):
        return u'%s %s' %(self.first_name, self.last_name)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.actorname)
```

I don't see what's wrong with my code, but in the django admin it is showing as `Actor Object`.

What am i doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Wouldn't you need to make `actorname` into a property to access it that way in `__unicode__`?

Comment: I don't think so, if i try it on the `first_name`, the same issue will occur.

Answer (score 3):

Remember it's a function, so it should be:

```
class Actor(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField('First Name', max_length=135)
    last_name = models.CharField('Last Name', max_length=135)

    class Meta:
        db_table = u'actor'

    def actorname(self):
        return u'%s %s' %(self.first_name, self.last_name)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.actorname())
```

Also, you could do:

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return u"%s %s" % (self.first_name, self.last_name)
```

Comment: Same issue, it didn't work. But what i noticed is, if I select the `Actor Object` and save it, I see `<bound method Actor.actorname of <Actor: Actor object>>` on the list display page.

Comment: As i told you, even if i write `return str(self.first_name)` nothing will change. Even thought, in other models, everything is working fine.

Comment: what about return u"%s" % self.actorname()?

Comment: Same problem, nothing is working in this model. I'm really confused.

Comment: What's displayed if you use the last solution I provided in my answer?

Comment: Tried it, same issue. I get `Actor Object`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, strange but it was because of the `actorname` method. Strange but worked after removing it.